# Ajax executes half of the success function after third call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, handlebars.js

I call ajax to draw a table from the mysql datas and put textareas below that table to be able to write a documentation for each fields.

Here's my problem. After I type the table name to the search field and click the button, I get the whole page as I wished. After I search for the same table name, I get the same page again, **but after I check the same table the third time, I only get two tables being drew.** The same issue occurs if I check `'test'` table once, then `'test2'` twice.

**UPDATE:** After the second ajax call (so if you type something and click to check meanwhile an other one is in the browser) the jQuery plugin only load the mysqlTable template and doesn't the textareas. Despite this textareas still appear, but if you call the third time any table then the issue occurs, the success function stops executing half-way and I only see two tables without textareas.

What I noticed is that the third time it calls ajax, it only executes until that part where I left the comment `/* *** this is the point where ...` That's the reason why textareas and other does not appear.

*It supposed to be like this.*
[image: It supposed to be like this.]

*But it looks like this after the third call.*
[image: But it looks like this after the third call]

I disable the search input while loading, in order to avoid multiple ajax call, but something happens here.

#### JS ajax call

```
function templatesHandling(){  
    clear();
    $('#textareaHolder').html('');
   $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/table.php?function=get_table_data&table="+tableName,
        dataType: "json", // it'll convert json to objects
        type : "GET",
        beforeSend : function(){ $('#ajax-loader-gif').show(); $('#search').attr({'disabled':'disabled','placeholder':'Loading...'});},
        complete : function(){ $('#ajax-loader-gif').hide(); $('#search').removeAttr('disabled').prop('placeholder','Type the table name..'); },
        error: function(er){ $("#check").after("<span id='error'>Error</span>"); },
        success: function(data){ 

        // add the current table name to the first object in order to be able to print out with {{tableName}}       

        if (!data[0].TableName){
            data[0].TableName = tableName; 
        }
           // call the 'table' template and send the data to work with
               $("#tableHolder").loadFromTemplate({
                   template :  "mysqlTable",
                   data : data
               });    

           /* *** this is the point where sometimes the ajax call stops executing *** */       

           // call the 'textareas' template and send the data to work with 
               $("#textareaHolder").loadFromTemplate({
                   template :  "textareas",
                   data : data
               });            

           /* *** parseWiki *** */
           $('#parseWikiHolder').show(); // show the last textarea 
           for (key in data[1]){ 
            res_head[++j] = '!scope="col"| '+ key + '\n'; // 
           }
           for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++){
                for(key in data[i]){
                    res_body[++j] = '|'+data[i][key]+'\n';
                }; // -for in | parse <tbody>
                res_body[++j] = '|-\n';  
           }; // -for | parse <tbody>   
        } // -success
    });
};
```

I use [jQuery HandlebarsJS](https://github.com/CKGrafico/jQuery_HandlebarsJS) to load Handlebars templates from separated files.

Do you have any thought about this issue? Why does it happen?
*(let me know if more code needed)*

### UPDATE

I inserted the **full JS code** of mine to JSFiddle, **[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ThePianist/ab57M/)**!

#### textareas (template)

```
{{#each this}}
    {{#if TableName}}
        <label for='{{TableName}}'>Description of <em class="tableName">{{TableName}}</em> table</label>
        <textarea id='{{TableName}}'></textarea>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if Field}}

        <label for='{{Field}}'>Description of <em class="tableName">{{Field}}</em> field</label>
        <textarea id='{{Field}}'></textarea>

    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

#### mysqlTable (template)

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        {{#each this}}
            {{#if TableName}}
                <th class="structure_thead" colspan="6">Structure of {{TableName}} table</th>
            {{/if}} 
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Field</th>     
        <th>Type</th> 
        <th>Null</th> 
        <th>Key</th> 
        <th>Default</th> 
        <th>Extra</th> 
    </tr>    
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    {{#each this}} 
    {{#if Field}}
        <tr> 
            <td><a href="#{{Field}}"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-link"></span>{{Field}}</a></td>
            <td>{{Type}}</td>
            <td>{{Null}}</td>
            <td>{{Key}}</td>
            <td>{{Default}}</td>
            <td>{{Extra}}</td>  
        </tr>   
    {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Doksi</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="searchHolder">
        <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Type the table name.."/>
        <input id="check" type="button" value="Check" />
        <img id="ajax-loader-gif" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" />
    </div>
    <div id="tableHolder"></div>
    <div id="textareaHolder"></div>
    <div id="parseWikiHolder">
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="Ready to copy?"/>
        <input id="copy" type="button" value="Hell, yeah!" />
        <textarea id="parseWiki"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.loadFromTemplate.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Get the table name - JSON file I receive

```
 [
    {
    table: "teszt"
    },
    {
    table: "teszt2"
    }
 ]
```

#### Get the table's data - JSON file I receive

```
 [
    {
    eredmeny: "siker"
    },
    {
    Field: "id",
    Type: "int(11)",
    Null: "NO",
    Key: "PRI",
    Default: null,
    Extra: "auto_increment"
    },
    {
    Field: "name",
    Type: "varchar(64)",
    Null: "NO",
    Key: "",
    Default: null,
    Extra: ""
    },
    {
    Field: "type",
    Type: "enum('y','n')",
    Null: "NO",
    Key: "",
    Default: "n",
    Extra: ""
    },
    {
    Field: "date",
    Type: "datetime",
    Null: "NO",
    Key: "",
    Default: null,
    Extra: ""
    }
    ]
```

### UPDATE 2

I commented out that jQuery plugin and tried a simple ajax call, but the same issue occurs. If I run this code, just the table will appear. If I change the code as textareas are in the first place, then only they will appear. **Why does the code stops executing without any error? Are the two ajax call kick each other out?**

#### The new ajax calls

```
 (function getTemplateAjax(path) {
        var source;
        var template;

        $.ajax({
            url: path, //ex. js/templates/mytemplate.handlebars
            cache: true,
            success: function(data) {
                source    = data;
                template  = Handlebars.compile(source);
                $('#tableHolder').html(template(o));
            }               
        });         
    })('templates/mysqlTable.html')     

    (function getTemplateAjax2(path) {
        var source;
        var template;

        $.ajax({
            url: path, //ex. js/templates/mytemplate.handlebars
            cache: true,
            success: function(data) {
                source    = data;
                template  = Handlebars.compile(source);
                $('#textareaHolder').html(template(o));
            }               
        });         
    })('templates/textareas.html')
```

Comment: Have you checked  the developer console? If a function unexpectedy stops midway, it's always or nearly always due to an exception being thrown.

Comment: Yes, I got nothing, but now I checked the network tab and I see I get twice the mysqlTable.html template. The question is now why it calls twice the file. No, it called 3 times. Hmm.

Comment: What is `loadFromTemplates`?

Comment: https://github.com/CKGrafico/jQuery_HandlebarsJS - I updated my post. I use jQuery HandlebarsJS to load Handlebars templates from separated files.

Comment: This piece of information should be in the question itself. Added it as a tag.

Comment: I noticed now that when I call second time the same tableName, the second time already does not call textareas.html, just mysqlTable.html, but textareas still appears and third time we know what happens. I tried to change them and call textareas before tables and then the same issue happened with them.. they appeared twice and now table didn't appear, because it was in the other half of the success funtion. I don't know why the ajax call stops executing the success function. :/

Comment: I think you'd need to share some more code to get an answer. There's nothing in particular that should halt the callback as far as I can see. What is `clear()` for example? What does the templates look like? What are the 3 JSON payloads you receive from the server that eventually cause things to go wrong?

Comment: Hmm. Not really sure what may cause the issue, I doubt it's something in this code. I added the rest of the code to the fiddle (some modifications to make it run). See if you can reproduce the problem there: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4KCg4/

Comment: This is the source of jQuery Handlebars .. https://github.com/CKGrafico/jQuery_HandlebarsJS/blob/master/js/functions/jquery.loadFromTemplate.js - I noticed some Ajax call inside it, of course because it calls the files from a different folder, but can it cause the issue? Ajax call inside an ajax call. Your code working good now, but I don't want to mix the main html file with templates, that's why I found this plugin. :) When I will have to deal with a rich in detail site, I think keeping separately the templates would make it more clean.

Comment: I deleted two lines from the clean() function. One that supposed to empty the tableHolder $('#tableHolder').empty(); and the other one that supposed to empty the textareaHolder $('#textareaHolder').empty(); CacheKiller is ON, so I refreshed and I noticed that only the table appears twice for the second load! I would expect that everything would appear twice, but nothing is happening with the textareas. Odd.

Comment: I wrote an other update, check that out!

Comment: Locating a problem is often about determining where there *isn't* a problem: narrowing down potential sources of errors. If you suspect that the problem is related to Handlebar's template ajax requests, try removing them (put the templates in the HTML file like I've done in the fiddle, for example). When they are loaded with ajax, you have to keep in mind that the parseWiki stuff and loops will execute **before** the templates are loaded. You can always split them out into separate files again later - when you've determined the problem. Apart from that, I'm pretty much out of suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @Frode! I appreciate your help! :) Check out my answer below, I 'detected' the problem, found a half-solution, now I will build it step by step to be more well-structured and less messy.

Answer (score 0):

### I found a (half)solution

As I copied that new code block to below UPDATE2, after I changed that again and found the (half)solution.

```
...
       success: function(o){ 
        // add the current table name to the first object in order to be able to print out with {{tableName}}       
                
           if (!o[0].TableName){
                o[0].TableName = tableName;
           };
       
            // call the 'mysqlTable' template and send the data to work with
            (function getTemplateAjax(objectum, path, element){
                var source, template; 
                $.ajax({
                    url: path,
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        source    = data;
                        template  = Handlebars.compile(source);
                        element.html(template(objectum));
                    }               
                }); 
            })(o, 'templates/mysqlTable.html', $('#tableHolder'));         
        
            // call the 'textareas' template and send the data to work with     
            (function getTemplateAjax(objectum, path, element){
                var source, template;
                $.ajax({
                    url: path,
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        source    = data;
                        template  = Handlebars.compile(source);
                        element.html(template(objectum));
                    }               
                });          
            })(o, 'templates/textareas.html', $('#textareaHolder'));
...
```

It's quite ugly and with more template files it won't the best practice, so I'll look for a better solution. At least it works now.

#### So the bug was probably inside the plugin. I am going to write my own jQuery plugin for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the async mode for the ajax call for that reason I just commited a new changes you can take a look into the examples:
        https://github.com/CKGrafico/jQuery_HandlebarsJS/commit/41eb4c7c39f9c1ef8bbd1015b594d0a33bb585ac maybe this could fix your problem.